# Displaying scope variable before view tag with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using Angular with the Ionic framework to build an app. I want to display the title of the previous screen in the header bar, next to the back button. Like so:

```
[ '<| title of previous screen'          'Title of current screen']
```

My thinking is to set a scope variable per view that I can then display in my title bar code.

I'm using this as index.html:

```
  <body ng-app="MyApp">

      <!-- The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate -->
      <nav-bar animation="nav-title-slide-ios7" 
           type="bar-positive" 
           back-button-type="button-icon" 
           back-button-icon="icon icon-back"
           back-button-label="{{backButtonLabel}}"
           ></nav-bar>

      <!-- where the content of each page will be rendered -->
     <nav-view animation="slide-left-right" back-button-label="{{backButtonLabel}}"></nav-view>

  </body>
```

The problem is, the scope variable is only available within the context of nav-view, but not in nav-bar. So the variable doesn't update. When you replace back-button-label with something static like 'HOME' or something, it does work.

Any idea how I can display the title of the previous screen in the title bar?

I've set up this Plunkr to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/BWsCQ98GAdw0I00pvCCk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add common parent scope to `nav-bar` and `nav-view` and declare your variable in it (using ng-init, or, better, separate controller for this parent) or just declare your variable on $rootScope.

Comment: Went for defining a separate controller on body. That made sure nav-bar could see any scope variables that were defined there.

Answer (score 0):

another option would be to use broadcast or emit with some type of history service.  check this out: http://motionharvest.com/2013/03/21/passing-arugments-to-on-in-angularjs-from-emit-and-broadcast/